# How consume soap using RSA-1_5 instead rsa-oaep-mgf1p

Tags: c#, encryption, soap

I have that code to encrypt my soap request:

```
    public static void EncryptSoapCommand(X509SecurityToken token, Security security)
    {
        var enc = new EncryptedData(token);
        security.Elements.Add(enc);
    }
```

And the token generation:

```
    public static X509SecurityToken GetEncryptToken(string certificateCrtPath)
    {
        var certificate = new X509Certificate2(certificateCrtPath);
        var encryptToken = new X509SecurityToken(certificate);

        return encryptToken;
    }
```

And when I send that, the following piece of xml is generated encryption information:

```
<xenc:EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#rsa-oaep-mgf1p">
   <ds:DigestMethod xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1" />
</xenc:EncryptionMethod>
```

But server is java developed and expects rsa-1_5. What I have to do, or where can I specify to C# use rsa-1_5 instead of rsa-oaep-mgf1p ?